# merging series from Pandas groupby to original dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have aggregated series from data frame using 'groupby' function as such code.

```
df.groupby(['username', 'week'])['variable'].agg(sum)
```

```
username     week     
zzzzoooeeeee 0     1.0
             1     NaN
             2     NaN
             3     NaN
             4     NaN
```

My original dataframe should look like this.

```
username     week    colA   colB        
zzzzoooeeeee  0       10     a   
zzzzoooeeeee  0       15     b   
zzzzoooeeeee  0       17     t    
zzzzoooeeeee  1       7      t   
zzzzoooeeeee  1       12     v   
zzzzoooeeeee  2       8      z   
zzzzoooeeeee  3       2      o   
zzzzoooeeeee  4       4      p
```

I'd like to merge my original data frame with the variable in the third column of the series based on 'username' and 'week'.

The output after merging should be like

```
username     week    colA   colB        
zzzzoooeeeee  0       10     a      1.0
zzzzoooeeeee  0       15     b      1.0
zzzzoooeeeee  0       17     t      1.0
zzzzoooeeeee  1       7      t     NaN
zzzzoooeeeee  1       12     v     NaN
zzzzoooeeeee  2       8      z     NaN
zzzzoooeeeee  3       2      o     NaN
zzzzoooeeeee  4       4      p     NaN
```

Can anyone please help this?

Comment: could you share first 5-10 rows of `df` and the final outcome you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your df example, which does not have 'variable' column so using 'colA' instead, we can achieve what you want using `merge`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['username', 'week'])['colA'].agg(sum).rename('colA_sum').reset_index()
df.merge(df2, on = ['username','week'])
```

output

```
    username        week    colA  colB      colA_sum
--  ------------  ------  ------  ------  ----------
 0  zzzzoooeeeee       0      10  a               42
 1  zzzzoooeeeee       0      15  b               42
 2  zzzzoooeeeee       0      17  t               42
 3  zzzzoooeeeee       1       7  t               19
 4  zzzzoooeeeee       1      12  v               19
 5  zzzzoooeeeee       2       8  z                8
 6  zzzzoooeeeee       3       2  o                2
 7  zzzzoooeeeee       4       4  p                4
```

The same, by the way, is achievable without `merge`:

```
df['colA_sum'] = df.groupby(['username', 'week'])['colA'].transform(sum)
```